# Can't figure out the answers to this Control Overflow test

Tags: javascript

I know that this is a very simple Javascript code so I appreciate your patience. Usually I am good with HTML/CSS but Javascript coding is new to me. I am trying to pass an online placement test for school and am having problems with what I know is a very simple test for anyone that knows Javascript. I can not for the life of me figure out the correct comparison operators for the following questions. I think I got #3 correct but the rest of them confuse me. I know the answers are right in front of me but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you

```
function exerciseOne(value){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // On the next line create a variable called 'greaterThan' and using a comparison operator, check to see if value is greater than 5.
  // Assign the results of that to 'greaterThan'
  greaterThan = value !=='5';  
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return greaterThan;
}
function exerciseTwo(value){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // On the next line create a variable called 'lessThan' and using a comparison operator, check to see if value is less than 20.
  // Assign the results of that to 'lessThan'
  lessThan = value !=='20'
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return lessThan;
}
function exerciseThree(value){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // On the next line create a variable called 'equalTo' and using a comparison operator, check to see if value is equal to 37.
  // Assign the results of that to 'equalTo'
  equalTo = value !=='37'
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return equalTo;
}
function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // You will also be given a variable named: greaterThanFive
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the value is greater than 5. If it is, re-assign greaterThanFive the boolean true.
  If = value !='5'
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return greaterThanFive;
}
function exerciseFive(name){
  let isSondra = false;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: name
  // You will also be given a variable named: isSondra
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the name is equal to the string 'Sondra'. If it is, re-assign isSondra the boolean true.
  
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return isSondra;**
```

Comment: See this [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison) on comparison operators.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Strings and numbers are different, `5 !== "5"`. Less than is `<`, greater than is `>`, less than or equal to is `<=` and you can hopefully figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming. First of all I think you would be able to answer these questions after taking a look at some online javascript documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/ is a good place to start. You want to look at 'operators' and 'control flow' by the looks of it.

in terms of your question, Q3 is almost right but you'll want to see if it is equal not if it is not equal. `equalTo = value == 37`

for the others you'll just need to know less than and more than `<` `>` etc. but take a look on the Mozilla page and you'll work it out in no time.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you study the following pages thoroughly so you may understand how comparison operators an if conditional statements are structured and work..

**If... else conditional:** [Mozilla on if... else conditional statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

**Operators:** [W3schools operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

```js
// I have done the hardest one for you to illustrate how the operator and
// if conditional statement works, I think you can figure the rest out
// with the links I and others have provided.

function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // You will also be given a variable named: greaterThanFive
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the value is greater than 5. If it is, re-assign greaterThanFive the boolean true.
  
  /* wrap the comparison operator in parenthesis if our value is greater 
   than 5 which is a basic algebretic style comparison */
  if(value > 5) 
  {
    /* code block wrapped in curly brackets "{ }" to run if the statement in the 
    parenthesis is true. The curly brackets are not required but is considered 
    it is a good practice to always use block statements */
    greaterThanFive = true;
  }  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return greaterThanFive;
}

/* variables to use within the console for display purposes only 
to illustrate this, simply change the value of the variable v to another number
and run the snippit again to see the difference of the comparison of teh two values*/
let v = 10;
let n = 5;

/* Here we are running the function exerciseFour() and passing the value of 10  
  into the value variable within the function, so value will actually represent 
  the number 10 with in the function. We are loging the function in the console. 
  The expected output will be true as 10 is greater than 5. */
console.log(`Is ${v} greater than ${n}?  ${exerciseFour(v)}`)
```